# How to select an element by part of class and text?

Tags: javascript, xpath, wdio

For a calendar, I have it setup as this:

```
<div class="Calendars__day___1LZkL">1</div>
<div class="Calendars__day___1LZkL">2</div>
<div class="Calendars__day___1LZkL">3</div>
<div class="Calendars__day___1LZkL">4</div>
```

and so on. I want to select the calendar day by class name and text but can't figure out how to get it to work.

I currently have a function setup like this:

```
    calendarDay(day) {
        return $(`[class^="Calendars__day"][text()="${day}"]`);
    }
```

but this throws an error "invalid selector: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified"

I'm using WDIO to run automation and that is what the selector is for

Comment: This is vanilla javascript or any specific framework?

Comment: We are using WDIO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the selector to use that works is:

```
$(`//div[contains(@class, "Calendars__day") and contains(., ${day})]`);
```